# Getting a 'nil:Nil Class' error in Ruby, but the array doesn't seem to empty

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I'm trying to code the 'Sieve of Eratosthenes' in Ruby and I'm having difficulty in the second 'while' loop. I want to test to see if `integers[j] % integers[0] == 0`, but the compiler keeps giving me a `nil:Nil Class` error at this line. I can't figure out the problem.

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i
puts

while n < 2
    puts 'Please enter an integer >= 2.'
    puts
    n = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts
end

integers = []

i = 0
while i <= n - 3
   integers[i] = i + 2
   i += 1
end

primes = []

j = 1 
while integers != []
    primes.push integers[0]
    while j <= integers.length
       if integers[j] % integers[0] == 0
           integers.delete(integers[j])
       end  
       j += 1
    end

    integers.shift    
    j = 1
end

puts integers 
puts
puts primes
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear, but my question is: why am I getting the following error:   'no method '%' for nil:Nil Class' on the line: if integers[j] % integers[0] == 0    ?

Comment: Please try and format code with the `{}` button. This is a train-wreck.

Comment: apologies, this is my first time posting...thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an off-by-one error. You're testing for `j <= integers.length`. So, for example, if you array has five items, the last iteration will be `integers[5]`. But the last index in a five-item array is 4 (because it starts at 0). You want `j < integers.length`.